# Android Notification Action not clickable

Tags: android, notifications, broadcastreceiver

I have a simple AsyncTask that is executing a background download and uses a notification to display feedback to the user. Additionally, this notification has an action to cancel the download. Upon clicking the action, a broadcast is supposed to be issued and my receiver class should grab it. However, i cannot click the button: it doesn't seem to be interactible in any way. All clicks fall through to the notification itself. If i set the PendingIntent on the content intent, it however works fine.

I'm running CyanogenMod Lollipop 5.0.2

Here is the code.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
    <receiver android:name=".CancelReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.warpten.dizzy.stopdownload"></action>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

**Async Task constructor**

```
    public DownloaderTask(Context ctx, SearchMatch info) {
        _context = ctx;
        _info = info;

        _notification = new Notification.Builder(_context);
        _notificationManager = (NotificationManager)_context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Intent actionIntent = new Intent("org.warpten.dizzy.stopdownload");
        actionIntent.putExtra("notificationId", _info.id);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(_context, 0, actionIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        _notification.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        if (ImageCache.HasImage(_info.id))
            _notification.setLargeIcon(ImageCache.GetImageBitmap(_info.id));
        // _notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); // This works
        _notification.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
            "Cancel", pendingIntent); // Doesn't work, cannot interact with the action
    }
```

The manager gets to notify the notification further down in doInBackground.

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
public class CancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    interface ICancelReceiver
    {
        void CancelDownload(int trackId);
    }

    public static ICancelReceiver Listener; // Lazyness to write a setter

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", -1);
        if (Listener != null && notificationId != -1)
            Listener.CancelDownload(notificationId);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a button in notification and you want to it to be clickable. You should use RemoteViews by that you will be able to perform action on button press.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add to your manifest file this

```
      <receiver
        android:name=".CancelReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />
```

Answer (score -1):

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<application>
      <receiver android:name=".CancelReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="org.warpten.dizzy.stopdownload"></action>
        </intent-filter>
     </receiver>
   </application>
```

**Async Task constructor**

```
class TestAsy extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public TestAsy(Context context){
        Log.e("TrackDownloaderDecrypterTask"," ");
        android.app.Notification.Builder mBuilder = new android.app.Notification.Builder(
                context);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent buttonIntent = new Intent("org.warpten.dizzy.stopdownload");
        buttonIntent.putExtra("notificationId", 1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                buttonIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
        mBuilder.setPriority(android.app.Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
        //Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.logosmall);
        //mBuilder.setLargeIcon(largeIcon);
        //Doesn't work, setLargeIcon That's why i am using setSmallIcon
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logosmall);

        mBuilder.addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel,
                "Cancel", pendingIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(0, mBuilder.build());
    }
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

};
```

**Broadcast Receiver**

```
    public class CancelReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

interface ICancelReceiver
{
    void CancelDownload(int trackId);
}

public static ICancelReceiver Listener; // Lazyness to write a setter

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Create Notification Manager
    NotificationManager notificationmanager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Dismiss Notification
    notificationmanager.cancel(0);
    Toast.makeText(context, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    int notificationId = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", -1);
    if (Listener != null && notificationId != -1)
        Listener.CancelDownload(notificationId);
}
```

}

Comment: How is this supposed to help me ? Apart from you dismissing the notification (which i do not want), i don't see any changes that would make the action work. Also, the problem is not the BroadcastReceiver, but in Notification.Builder.addAction : i cannot click the "Cancel" action that is created.

Comment: Boss you want cancel action or  cancelDowload action

Comment: @Warpten have you found any solution?